# Firebase RealTime Database Delete First 20 item

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference newReferance = database.getReference().child("Users");
    Query query = newReferance.orderByChild("timestamp");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatMessages.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                //String userMail = hashMap.get("useremail");
                String userMessage = hashMap.get("usermessage");
                String userCt = hashMap.get("usershow");
                chatMessages.add(userCt + ": " + userMessage);
                if (chatMessages.size() >= 10){
                    for (int i= 0; i < 5; i++){
                        //HOW ????
                    }
                }
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

Hi Dear guys. How do I select and delete the first 5 data in a real-time database? When the ArrayList reaches a certain limit, I want to delete the first 5 data from the database. I'd appreciate it if you could help with the problem.

Comment: When your `ArrayList` size reaches the limit where you want to delete items you could create and run another `Query` by adding `limitToFirst(int numberOfItems)` in your case parameter would be `5` and than delete those 5 returned items from `Query`

Comment: To delete items you can create a reference to the items in your for loop and then use the setValue() function, and set a null value. As for getting the first 5 items see @Yupi comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I select and delete the first 5 data in a real-time database?

You can achieve this using Firebase Query's [limitToFirst(int limit)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#limitToFirst(int)):

> Create a query with limit and anchor it to the start of the window

And in code should look like this:

```
Query query = newReferance.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(5);
```

See I have used this `limitToFirst()` method that can help you find the first 5 items. To delete them, just attach a listener and inside the `onDataChange()` method use the following line of code:

```
dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
```

Comment: I tried but again all the data was deleted. It didn't just erase the first 5 data.

Comment: It cannot be as you say. It's working 100% because I see that you have already answered your question using my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
final DatabaseReference newReferance = database.getReference().child("Users");
    final Query query = newReferance.orderByChild("timestamp");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatMessages.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                //String userMail = hashMap.get("useremail");
                String userMessage = hashMap.get("usermessage");
                String userCt = hashMap.get("usershow");
                chatMessages.add(userCt + ": " + userMessage);
                if (chatMessages.size() >= 10){
                    Query query1 = newReferance.limitToFirst(5);
                    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            database.getReference().child("Users").setValue(null);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

Although I'm set, it's all deleted. I can't erase the items I want. All cleared.

Answer (score 0):

rootRef is the firebase database reference. whose instance we have to gained before trying to delete any value. you can see the code given below.

```
count = 0;
    rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                CommonLocationClass user = postSnapshot.getValue(CommonLocationClass.class);
                if (count < 5) {
                    rootRef.child(user.getPhNo).removeValue();
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError firebaseError){

    }
});
```

the CommonLocationClass is a getter setter model class i have made to make the fire-base implementation easy

you can try this it works for me

Comment: Can I do it without using CommonLocationClass?

Comment: if you have multiple parameters in a single child then you will have to use a Model class or you wont be able to fetch the proper parameter you need, but if you have a single parameter in the child then you can just cast the postSnapshot to a string or any other datatype and get the value

Comment: Under one child there are many parameters but I want to delete them all. Only the first 5 data delete.

Comment: yes then for hat u'll have to create a model class with that you can delete using the above code i have posted .  To update and add the fields using the same method of model class you can use my solution posted [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835579/8906934)

Comment: so as in my above given solution just replace the user.getPhNo with the child id's which in your case are something like "de2705eb-2nfei329-324u78" etc and all the data under those Id's will get deleted

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void getDataFirebase() {

    /*if (chatMessages.size() == MAX_MSJ_LIMIT){
        database.getReference().child("Users").removeValue();
    }*/
    final DatabaseReference newRefere = database.getReference().child("Users");
    Query query = newRefere.orderByChild("timestamp");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatMessages.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                //String userMail = hashMap.get("useremail");
                String userMessage = hashMap.get("usermessage");
                String userCt = hashMap.get("usershow");
                chatMessages.add(userCt + ": " + userMessage);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    if (chatMessages.size() >= 10) {
        Query query1 = newRefere.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(5);
        query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

It didn't just erase the first 5 data.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (chatMessages.size() >= 10) {
        Query query1 = newRefere.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(5);
        query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ds.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I solved the problem. With this code

Comment: So this is basically the same solution as I provided you in my answer, right?