# How to arrange firebase database items for each android user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I Am creating an android app to store the name and mobile number of each users, now when the second user updating his information it is removing the first user's information stored in database ,  I have 2 fragments one is sign in fragment (using firebase auth) and the second fragment to get name& mobile number. How can i add information for each user separately

[image]

This is my sign in in code

```
 btn_signIn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_btn);
    btn_signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String emailID = username.getText().toString();
            String paswd = password.getText().toString();
            if (emailID.isEmpty()) {
                username.setError("Provide your Email first!");
                username.requestFocus();
            } else if (paswd.isEmpty()) {
                password.setError("Set your password");
                password.requestFocus();
            }
            else if (emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (!(emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty())) {


                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, paswd)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                       // inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                      //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomePageActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                   // finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

.

```
            }







        }
    });
```

This is my code to store mobile number in firebase which is in another fragment

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Please Input Contact Information").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer).setView(
                    layout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
                    EditText inputMobile = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_mobile);
                    if (inputMobile.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        return;
                    }
                    try{
                        long number = Long.valueOf(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        SPManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).setMobile(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        mTextMobile.setText(inputMobile.getText().toString());


                        String mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString();
                        DatabaseReference mynum = database.getReference("number");




                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Input Correct Phone Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help to store information separately for each user, i searched this a lot but nothing helped me. may be because i am very newbie..please help me

Comment: use their auth.getcurentUser id for unique key

Comment: after getting the unique key what should i do

Comment: share you firebase database structure as well

Comment: could you please share code where you are storing data.?

Comment: see my question ihv added@AtifAbbAsi

Comment: use fcm id as parent node and insert all other child nodes in that. u will have separate user details and nodes

Comment: what is fcm ?? can u give me some idea of code and let me know how it will be with an answer@null

Comment: this way you not store the every user data . you get the current  login user firebase authentication key then you create the one child(userid) .child("number") ,this way is dynamically. hope it helpfull for you

Comment: rootRef.child("delivery").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(Delivery.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code 
add products using the below code

```
DatabaseReference rootRef;
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 CommonLocationClass dataLocation = new CommonLocationClass();
            dataLocation.setLat(latLng.latitude);
            dataLocation.setLongi(latLng.longitude);
            dataLocation.setPhno("");
            dataLocation.setStatus(true);
            if (sessionManager.phNO() != null) {
                rootRef.child(sessionManager.phNO()).setValue(dataLocation);
            }
```

the commonlocationclass is a model class having getters and setters
.child(sessionManager.phNo()) is the child name by which you can further identify the items

and by this code you can update the fields

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("lat", latLng.latitude);
            map.put("longi", latLng.longitude);
            map.put("phno", sessionManager.phNO());
            map.put("status", true);
            if (sessionManager.phNO() != null)
                rootRef.child(sessionManager.phNO()).updateChildren(map);
```

Try this code hope it will help you happy coding!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Please Input Contact Information").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer).setView(
                    layout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
                    EditText inputMobile = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_mobile);
                    if (inputMobile.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        return;
                    }
                    try{
                        long number = Long.valueOf(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        SPManipulation.getInstance(getActivity()).setMobile(inputMobile.getText().toString());
                        mTextMobile.setText(inputMobile.getText().toString());

            FirebaseAuth   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        String mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString();
                        DatabaseReference mynum = database.getReference().child(userID).child("number");




                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Input Correct Phone Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Hope it's help full for you